# In python doit (pydoit), what is the expected behaviour of watch parameter

Tags: fedora, watch, doit

For a task, I have following metadata:

```
def task_build_tgz():
    return {
        'actions': [do_action],
        'targets': targets,
        'uptodate': [run_once],
         
        'watch': watch_dirs
    }
```

The watch_dirs is bunch of dirs. My expectation was when a file changes in one of the watch_dirs, the task would be reevaluated. I get this behaviour with file_dep. But not with watch parameter. Is this expected or is it a bug. I am running this on fedora?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `auto` sub-command, the output include only executed tasks.
If the task is up-to-date it does not produce any output.

You are using `run_once` on your task. So it will not be executed again...